# joedixon/laravel-translation not updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have just installed a Joedixon/Laravel-translation package in Laravel version  8.
It shows the words but when I want to update it will not work.
I did everything that was said in the documentation and also I've read this article about it but it also didn't work.
https://github.com/joedixon/laravel-translation/issues/82

NOTES:

1: I changed the driver to database.

2: adding a new Language works fine

3: while adding new translation it searches in http://localhost/languages/en instead of http://localhost/project_name/languages/en

When I try to update a word it says 404 not found in the console:
[image: Console view]
Routes:

```
ticate:sanctum    |
|        | POST     | api/login                                |                               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                             | api
                  |
|        | POST     | api/register                             |                               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register                          | api
                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                                 |                               | Closure                                                                    | api
                  |
|        |          |                                          |                               |                                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum    |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                                     | home                          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                                  | web
                  |
|        |          |                                          |                               |                                                                            | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate            |
|        | GET|HEAD | languages                                | languages.index               | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageController@index             | web
                  |
|        | POST     | languages                                | languages.store               | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageController@store             | web
                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | languages/create                         | languages.create              | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageController@create            | web
                  |
|        | POST     | languages/{language}                     | languages.translations.update | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageTranslationController@update | web
                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | languages/{language}/translations        | languages.translations.index  | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageTranslationController@index  | web
                  |
|        | POST     | languages/{language}/translations        | languages.translations.store  | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageTranslationController@store  | web
                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | languages/{language}/translations/create | languages.translations.create | JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers\LanguageTranslationController@create | web
                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                                    | login                         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                    | web
```

Languages Translation Controller

```
<?php

namespace JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use JoeDixon\Translation\Drivers\Translation;
use JoeDixon\Translation\Http\Requests\TranslationRequest;

class LanguageTranslationController extends Controller
{
    private $translation;

    public function __construct(Translation $translation)
    {
        $this->translation = $translation;
    }

    public function index(Request $request, $language)
    {
        // dd($this->translation->getSingleTranslationsFor('en'));
        if ($request->has('language') && $request->get('language') !== $language) {
            return redirect()
                ->route('languages.translations.index', ['language' => $request->get('language'), 'group' => $request->get('group'), 'filter' => $request->get('filter')]);
        }

        $languages = $this->translation->allLanguages();
        $groups = $this->translation->getGroupsFor(config('app.locale'))->merge('single');
        $translations = $this->translation->filterTranslationsFor($language, $request->get('filter'));

        if ($request->has('group') && $request->get('group')) {
            if ($request->get('group') === 'single') {
                $translations = $translations->get('single');
                $translations = new Collection(['single' => $translations]);
            } else {
                $translations = $translations->get('group')->filter(function ($values, $group) use ($request) {
                    return $group === $request->get('group');
                });

                $translations = new Collection(['group' => $translations]);
            }
        }

        return view('translation::languages.translations.index', compact('language', 'languages', 'groups', 'translations'));
    }

    public function create(Request $request, $language)
    {
        return view('translation::languages.translations.create', compact('language'));
    }

    public function store(TranslationRequest $request, $language)
    {
        if ($request->filled('group')) {
            $namespace = $request->has('namespace') && $request->get('namespace') ? "{$request->get('namespace')}::" : '';
            $this->translation->addGroupTranslation($language, "{$namespace}{$request->get('group')}", $request->get('key'), $request->get('value') ?: '');
        } else {
            $this->translation->addSingleTranslation($language, 'single', $request->get('key'), $request->get('value') ?: '');
        }

        return redirect()
            ->route('languages.translations.index', $language)
            ->with('success', __('translation::translation.translation_added'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $language)
    {
        if (! Str::contains($request->get('group'), 'single')) {
            $this->translation->addGroupTranslation($language, $request->get('group'), $request->get('key'), $request->get('value') ?: '');
        } else {
            $this->translation->addSingleTranslation($language, $request->get('group'), $request->get('key'), $request->get('value') ?: '');
        }

        return ['success' => true];
    }
}
```

List of routes

```
<?php

Route::group(config('translation.route_group_config') + ['namespace' => 'JoeDixon\\Translation\\Http\\Controllers'], function ($router) {
    $router->get(config('translation.ui_url'), 'LanguageController@index')
        ->name('languages.index');

    $router->get(config('translation.ui_url').'/create', 'LanguageController@create')
        ->name('languages.create');

    $router->post(config('translation.ui_url'), 'LanguageController@store')
        ->name('languages.store');

    $router->get(config('translation.ui_url').'/{language}/translations', 'LanguageTranslationController@index')
        ->name('languages.translations.index');

    $router->post(config('translation.ui_url').'/{language}', 'LanguageTranslationController@update')
        ->name('languages.translations.update');

    $router->get(config('translation.ui_url').'/{language}/translations/create', 'LanguageTranslationController@create')
        ->name('languages.translations.create');

    $router->post(config('translation.ui_url').'/{language}/translations', 'LanguageTranslationController@store')
        ->name('languages.translations.store');
});
```

Comment: Are you using route model binding(RMB)?

Comment: NO just normal routing

Comment: How is `LanguageTranslationController@update` getting the language is it findOrfail?

Comment: I have Edited the question and  added LanguageTranslationsCOntroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the Problem which was completely in different place

it's in public/vendor/translation/js/app.js

```
        methods: {
            setActive: function () {
                this.isActive = !0, this.$refs.trans.focus()
            },
            storeTranslation: function () {
                var e = this;
                this.isActive = !1, this.hasChanged && (this.isLoading = !0, window.axios.post
                    ("/MY_PROJECT_NAME/public".concat("/").concat(this.route, "/").concat(this.language), {
                    language: this.language,
                    group: this.group,
                    key: this.translationKey,
                    value: this.translation
                }).then((function (t) {
                    e.hasSaved = !0, e.isLoading = !1, e.hasChanged = !1
                })).catch((function (t) {
                    e.hasErrored = !0, e.isLoading = !1
                })))
            }
        },
```

just added **("/MY_PROJECT_NAME/public".concat("/")** and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you run

```
php artisan optimize
```

since installation to clear the route cache and allow it to pick up the new routes that you've added to web.php?

Comment: thanks. yes but still showing same problem